# Segmentation fault (core dumped)-cannot fix error

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, boost, memory-segmentation

I am having trouble with the following bit of code. I am using Boost to do the matrix multiplication. I am using Gtesting to test my code. When I test the following bit of code I get the following error.

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I know that is has to do with the pointers I am using, but I cant find the error. I have tried a couple of things but with no luck. My code is the following. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

```
BLAS::matrix<double>* PolyFilter::getCoef(const std::queue<double> y const std::queue<double> x, const BLAS::vector<double>& w)
{
    int size = y.size();
    queue<double> yList = y;
    BLAS::matrix<double> pos(size,1);
    BLAS::matrix<double>* vand = makeVandermondeMatrix(x);
    BLAS::matrix<double>* weights = makeDiag(w);
    BLAS::matrix<double> *temp1,*temp2,*temp3,*temp4,*temp5;
    BLAS::matrix<double>* temp6 = new BLAS::matrix<double>(size,size);
    std::cout<<size<<endl;


    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        pos.insert_element(i,0,yList.front());
        yList.pop();
    }

    *temp1 = BLAS::prod(BLAS::trans(*vand), *weights);

    *temp2 = BLAS::prod(*temp1, *vand);


    if( rfalInverse(*temp2, *temp3) )
    {
        *temp4 = BLAS::prod(*temp3, BLAS::trans(*vand));
        *temp5 = BLAS::prod(*temp4,*weights);
        *temp6 = BLAS::prod(*temp5, BLAS::trans(pos));  
    } 



    return temp6;

}
```

Thankyou for any help. This error is driving me crazy.

Comment: *Where* does the crash happen? Please run a debug-build in a debugger to catch the crash in action, and use the debugger to locate the site of the crash in your code.

Comment: You said you tried a couple of things. What did you try? Have you tried using `gdb`?

Comment: The immediately obvious bug is that you don't initialize `temp1` (don't allocate space for it to point to) but then assign a value to `*temp1`.  Was that an oversight?  Or do you need to learn the basics of pointers in C/C++?

Answer (score 3):

You declared several pointers:

```
BLAS::matrix<double> *temp1,*temp2,*temp3,*temp4,*temp5;
```

And then you immediately proceed to dereference the uninitialized pointers:

```
*temp1 = BLAS::prod(BLAS::trans(*vand), *weights);

*temp2 = BLAS::prod(*temp1, *vand);
```

There's your problem.

P.S. You should invest some time in learning how to use a debugger. This should be trivial to figure out with a debugger.